# Visual Studio 2010 Rebuild All then run unit tests builds all again

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, building

In Visual Studio 2010 I do the following:

- Build > Rebuild Solutuion.

  No errors, no warnings.
- Solution > Run StyleCop (Rescan All)

  No errors, no warnings.
- Test > Run > All tests in solution.

  A build kicks off again - why is this?  Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 0):

Well as no-one has answered I will offer my workaround.

Make changes, then run the tests without building first.  This will obviously do a build, but 1 only.